# CScrollBar in CWnd

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a class CForm which has a COblist with pages. Every page has a list with controls (like radio button, checkboxes etc).  CForm has also a CList where a FormPanel is a CWnd with a CTabCtrl. For every page there is a FormPanel. CForm has also a CWnd with a CScrollBar and a method SetPanel();

[image]

The form is created from an XML like:

```
<Form><Page><Radiobutton></Radiobutton></Page></Form>
```

The form is loaded into a CFormView where its controls is loaded on a panel, the panel is placed in the panel(CWnd) with the scrollbar.

My main problem is that the controls isn't visible until I hoover with the mouse over it or use the scrollbar.

Before hoover:

[image]

After hoover:

[image]

So the controls are there and I can use them, but how I get them to show from the start?

I've tried to change from CWnd with a CScrollBar to a CFormView but it didn't work. Because my CTabCtrl wants a CWnd and not a CFormView, and I don't want to change the structure too much (Like adding propertypages instead of CWnds for panels)

So, any idea how I can get this to work?

Edit:

```
void CForm::Show()
{
       m_pclScrollbar = new CFormularScrollbar(m_pwndParent, &m_clRect);
       m_pclScrollbar->SetPanel(m_pclPanel);
       m_pclScrollbar->ScrollBarInit();
       m_pclScrollbar->Show();
       m_pclPanel->Show();
       m_pclPanel->RedrawWindow();
}
```

edit 2:

```
    m_pclTabCtrl = new CTabCtrl();
    if(!m_pclTabCtrl->Create(TCS_TABS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rectTabCtrl, this, IDC_TAB_FORMULAR))
        throw new CBException("CFormPanel", "TabCtrlInit", "Could not create");
```

Edit 3:

Is it possible to have the Scrollbar in the same CWnd as the controllers? or do I move the scrollbar when I scroll?

Comment: Did you try to [redraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fdz8ey6.aspx) the window yet ?

Comment: Yes, the controls is shown for .1 second and then hidden behind the grey again.

Comment: `Because my CTabCtrl wants a CWnd and not a CFormView` but you realize that [`CFormView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/353dcby6.aspx#Anchor_3) inherits down the structure from `CWnd` ?

Comment: Yes, I do. But it throws an exception when 'this' is a CFormView and works great when its a "real" CWnd. `m_pclTabCtrl->Create(TCS_TABS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rectTabCtrl, this, IDC_TAB_FORMULAR)`

Comment: What exception does it throw ? Could you show the declaration/initialization/allocation of `m_pclTabCtrl` too ?

Comment: I was wrong. It does not throw an exception, it only returns false. See edit

Comment: Please try `this->RedrawWindow();` instead of the call to `m_pclPanel` and post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (you could upload a solution somewhere, so we can debug). It's hard to guess where something might be wrong.